# Update database values using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have a php application for showing some pictures stored in a database. I want to use javascript to change photos order. Index.php page looks like:

```
$photos = array();
$photos_query = "SELECT * FROM `photos` WHERE `id`=".$_SESSION['id']."ORDER BY `order`";
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $photos_query);
while ($photos_row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
    $photos[] = array(
                'photo_id' => $photos_row['photo_id'], 
                'id' => $photos_row['id'], 
                'photo_name' => $photos_row['photo_name'], 
                'order' => $photos_row['photo_order']
            );
} ... 
<div id="message"></div>
<div id="showphotos">
    if (empty($photos)) {
        echo 'No photos';
    } else {
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ($photos as $photo) {
            echo '<li id="photoid_'.$photo['photo_id'].'">
           <img src="uploads/', $photo['id'], '/', $photo['photo_id'],'"' .$photo['photo_name']. 'height="150" width="150">
           ...       </li>';    
        } echo '</ul>';
  }
</div>
```

This page calls move.js once user tries to change image's position:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    function slideOut(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("#message").slideUp("slow", function () {});
        }, 2000);
    };

    $("#message").hide();

    $(function() {
        $('ul').sortable({
            cursor: 'move',
            opacity: 0.7,
            revert: false,
            update: function(){
                var neworder = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&update=update';
                $.post("change_image_position.php", neworder, function (themessage) {
                    $("#message").html(themessage);
                    $("#message").slideDown('slow');
                    slideOut();
                });
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Finally change_image_position.php contains:

```
$array = $_POST['photoid'];
if ($_POST['update'] == "update"){
    $count = 1;
    foreach ($array as $idval) {
        $query = "UPDATE photos SET order = " . $count . " WHERE photo_id = " . $idval;
        mysqli_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
        $count ++;
    }
    echo 'All saved! refresh the page to see the changes';
}
```

I am facing two problems... First, order by statement(index.php) is not working and second, query for altering photos through database query(change_image_position.php) does not return any result. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I would suggest tidying up your code first of all :)

Comment: in your `change_image_position.php` file, do a `var_dump($_POST)` and paste the posted information. Make sure you have your error reporting turned all the way up (`ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`). You have some issues with syntax in your SQL statement in your `index.php` file as well (spaces, quoting - assuming session ID is not an integer, etc).

Comment: After changing '$update=update'; to "&update=update"; var_dump($_POST) prints  array(2) { ["photoid"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "1" [2]=> string(1) "2" } ["update"]=> string(6) "update" } Error, insert query failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mySQL statement has a missing space -

```
$photos_query = "SELECT * FROM `photos` WHERE `id`=".$_SESSION['id']."ORDER BY `order`";
```

Should be

```
$photos_query = "SELECT * FROM `photos` WHERE `id`=".$_SESSION['id']." ORDER BY `order`";
```

I think the way you are currently doing the photo saving is failing on the `neworder` portion.

You currently pass in `$update` and then call `$_POST['update']` which would be looking for just `update=update`.

Comment: About the sql statement you were right. So what would you suggest for the second part? (I changed '$update=update'; to "&update=update";)

Comment: Problem solved... It had a problem connecting to mysql database properly... Thanks for help...